# Space efficiency of Btrfs reflinks vs hardlinks

Tags: disk-usage, btrfs, hard-link, duplicate, file-metadata

[A webpage referenced](https://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/unix_links.html) by the [Wikipedia article on Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#cite_note-55) claims that (emphasis mine)

> [Btrfs] reflinks have the same use as hardlinks, but are **more space efficient**.

I thought that the opposite was true—that hardlinks are more space-efficient because a hardlink creates only a directory entry that points to the existing inode, whereas a reflink creates a directory entry, an inode, and file metadata.

Furthermore, a reflink duplicates file data if the data is [inlined within the metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614130/btrfs-resultant-copy-is-twice-the-size-of-source/645028#645028), whereas this never happens with a hardlink because there is no new metadata for the file.

Am I correct?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct to me. I would even disagree with the other part of the quoted statement: "reflinks have the same use as hardlinks". No, they don't have the same use, because if you subsequently open the file by one of its 2 names and make modifications, something entirely different happens in each case.